# Missing credentials in config when trying to put object to s3 bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I've got an express service that is trying to write an object to an s3 bucket but I'm getting the following error:

> Missing credentials in config

I'm assuming my AWS role locally which sets my credentials in `.aws/credentials` then in my Dockerfile I am copying them into my container.

```
RUN mkdir "/home/node/.aws" && touch "/home/node/.aws/config" && touch "/home/node/.aws/credentials"
RUN echo "${AWS_CREDENTIALS}" > "/home/node/.aws/credentials"
```

The documentation says:

> The SDK automatically detects AWS credentials set as variables in your
> environment and uses them for SDK  requests, eliminating the need to
> manage credentials in your application. The environment variables that
> you set to provide your credentials are:
>
> AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
>
> AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
>
> AWS_SESSION_TOKEN (optional)

So I don't have to manually manage my credentials when using the sdk?

Currently the code for writing to the s3 bucket:

```
import s3 from 'aws-sdk/clients/s3';

const s3Client = new s3({region: process.env['region']});

async upload() {
   const params = {
      Bucket: process.env['bucket'],
      Key: 'test.json',
      Body: somejsonfile
   }

   const res = s3Client.upload(params).promise();
   return results;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is **node** the right user that execute this code?

Is the file `/home/node/.aws/credentials` looks like something like that:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = <AAK>
aws_secret_access_key = <ASK>
```

To debug, you can try try the following:
You can try to add your AWS credentials directly in the code like that:

```
AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId: "<AAK>",
    secretAccessKey: "<ASK>",
    "region": "<REGION>"
});
```

Alternatively, you can try to delete `/home/node/.aws/credentials` file and move the credentials to `/home/node/.aws/config` file instead:

```
[default]
region=<REGION>
output=json
aws_access_key_id = <AAK>
aws_secret_access_key = <ASK>
```

And alternatively you can try to add credentials and region as env variables in your Dockerfile:

```
ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<AAK>
ENV AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<ASK>
ENV AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=<REGION>
```